# Http-server to access the application without port

Tags: node.js, npm, debian, httpserver

So I have a web application being run on an http-server via npm. In my package.jsonfile, I have the line "start": "http-server dist --ssl", and my app runs fine when I go to https://myipaddress:8080. However if I change the url to just http://myipaddress, i cant access the application

So in short, how cant i run the application so i can access it from https://myipaddress and not https://myipaddress:8080 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A browser without special plugins (i.e. [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)) expects port 80 for `http://` scheme. If you used `https://myipaddress`, then it would expect port 443.

So in order browser call to `http://myipaddress` you need two actions:

- A redirect from HTTP to HTTPS (from http://myipaddress:80 to http://myipaddress:443)
- Your application to listen on port 443 so https://myipaddress would work

NGINX or other reverse proxy might help.

You could make `http-server` to listen on `localhost:8080` without SSL and place NGINX so it would redirect `http://myipaddress:80` to `https://myipaddress:443` and proxy `https://myipaddress:443` to `http://localhost:8080`

Also, keep in mind that listening on a port lower than 1024 needs root user permissions on Unix systems.

Comment: Hi.

Thanks! i tried to run the application with the setting "server": "http-server dist --ssl -p 443", and that worked so i could access it from -https://https://myipaddress without a problem.

I also have a domain, https://https://example.com that i access my server with. I tried to access my application with that on -https://https://example.com  and -https://https://example.com:443 but i am only meet with the error: 404 Not Found nginx/1.4.7 Do you know why?

Comment: Hey. I'm glad it worked. :-) Regarding DNS, it might be a lot of different problems, i.e. domain points to a different IP than your server. Do you have nginx running on your server?

Comment: To find out which IP does the DNS point to, you can use `host` or `ping` commands, i.e.
```
ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.21.131): 56 data bytes
```
So you can see that google.com points to `172.217.21.131`